# DRF - How to concatanate serialized model with custom field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I need to concateanate serialized models with custom field = list[]

[image]

I have a user_profile model and I want to know if particular user is "mine(active user's)" friend, in the users list (list_boolean = ["True", "False", "True"])

views.py:

```
class User_profile_view(APIView):
    def get(self, request): 

        #this is example list which i need to link
        list_boolean = ["True", "False", "True"]
        query = User_profile.objects.all()
        serializer_class = User_profile_serializer(query, many=True)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

models.py:

```
class User_profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

serializer.py:

```
class User_profile_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User_profile
        exclude = ["id"]
```

Is there any way to link particular list, to objects? it might be inside of the object (which is better) or outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to add this information.

```
class User_profile_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User_profile
        exclude = ["id"]    
    is_friend = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_is_friend(self, ob):
        #some query to determine if the user in question (ob) is a friend with the current user (self.context['current_user'])
        return True/False
```

Comment: can i pass in this serializer any variables? for example i need to pass "user_myself = request.user" variable to compare, if "THIS particular user from serialzer (from queryset)" is a friend  to "user_myself" ? Because with "get_is_friend" i can only retrive data of 1 user, but i need two to compare.As you said (self.context['current_user']) how would i send here a context?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `ob` is each user record, and `self.context['current_user']` will be the user making the request.

Comment: i was asking how to send variable as context, it is empty by default. Solved it with this: in views.py `serializer_class = User_profile_serializer(query, context={'user': request.user},many=True)` and in this way i can retrieve user who made a request in serializer.py with `self.context['user']`

Comment: Ah, you shouldn't need to do that, context is passed to the serializer in DRF, which contains the request by default. So you should be able to use self.context['request'].user inside your serializer.